# Integral of a force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

I have what is probably quite a basic question:

> A block of mass 5 kg is subject to a force $\ F = 3x + 5x^2 $ (in N). The block is initially at rest at $\ x = 1$. Its speed when $\ x = 5$ is:

Somehow I solved this problem by taking the integral of the force and dividing out the time and mass but I really have no idea why this worked.

I understand dividing out mass since $\ F = ma$ but the integral of the force is potential...? and time?

If anyone could shed light on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are given the force as a function of position, so it would be simpler to look at the work the force does rather than think about accelerations which involve knowing how the force changes in time for that specific path.

$$W=\int F dx=\int_1^5 (3x+5x^2) dx$$

From there you can use the work-kinetic energy relation
$$W=\Delta K$$

I leave the details to you.

The problem with trying to integrate the force with respect to time is that you would need to know what $x(t)$ is beforehand, which we do not know. As I said before, $F(t)$ depends on what $x(t)$ is, whereas $F(x)$ just depends on $x$ without any depdence on how $x$ actually changes in time.